# Receiving error in Search Log: The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service

Tags: search

I deleted about 250 documents from a document library (through the Windows Explorer view). After conducting a full crawl, I see about 250 errors in the Search Log that say this:

**The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site:**  Root element is missing. )*

I have run a few more full crawls and the errors still exist; however, the documents for which these errors are being thrown do not exist in the document library. I also cleared the Recycle Bin and re-ran a full crawl. Errors are still thrown.

Also, is there issues with deleting documents from Windows Explorer view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the errors are just saying we cant find this reference from the index file, they should really be warnings and not errors in my opinion. If you reset your index and do a full crawl you should no longer receive those errors.

Comment: I really wish I wouldn't have to reset the Index, but I'll go that route. Thanks.